# Always fails to convert to datetime because of backslash

Tags: c#, json

I have a json string date value as below:

```
{[
   {
     "id": "2044020453",
     "startDate": "2022-11-19T04:14:11+07:00",
     "endDate": "2022-11-19T04:14:11+07:00",
  }
]}

string endDate = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jo["endDate"], Formatting.None, new 
JsonSerializerSettings
{
   DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc
});


endDate value is "\"2022-11-18T21:14:11Z\""

DateTime endDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(endDate, "yyyy-MM- 
ddTHH:mm:ssZ",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Always fails to convert to date because there is a backslash in-front and end of the "endDate"

how to clean the backslash?

I have tried:

```
endDate.Replace("\\", "") --> no luck
Regex.Unescape(endDate) also no luck
```

anybody can help?

Comment: _"how to clean the backslash?"_ - don't. Just don't add it in the first place. Wouldn't that be simpler? You're serializing the endDate value, which is a string, so you get a serialized string, which starts and ends with quotation marks. Represented through the debugger in Visual Studio, you will see the string literal.

Comment: I'm not serializing the date, but it returns from an API and I have to convert it to UTC

Comment: _"I'm not serializing the date"_ - So what's this?: `string endDate = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jo["endDate"]` - you're serializing the date string!

Comment: Is this a valid json @Dev

Comment: In case you're somehow still confused: `string endDate = jo["endDate"].ToString();`

Comment: Why are you serializing a the date that is already serialized to a string?

Comment: Why not just parse the given string to a `DateTime` then convert that to UTC?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's a double quote that needs to be removed:

```
endDate.Replace("\"", "")
```

Comment: Or OP could just not unnecessarily serialize the date string, thereby avoiding having the quoted string in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is no backslash but a quote character around the string, which is just escaped by the backslash. So actually the string is:

```
"2022-11-18T21:14:11Z"
```

then you can trim it:

```
endDate = endDate.Trim('"');
```

and then parse it:

```
DateTime endDateTime = DateTime.Parse(endDate, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

[DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Uz2Y1e)